# Can't access custom properties of a linked characters proxy rig

Tags: properties, linked-data, rigify, proxies

I have a rigified character.
I added a custom property to the rig object to drive a shape key on the face. It works as expected in the original file: the custom property slider of the rig drives the shape key on the face.

For ease of iteration, I link the rig (as a collection) into my animation file and make a proxy out of the rig so I can animate it. Animating the rig controls works as desired.

The problem is: the Custom properties of said rig are greyed out and inaccessible in the files where the rig is linked.
This makes it impossible to animate the shape keys for the face.

Is there a way to unlock custom properties in a linked proxy rig ?
if not, is there a workaround people use to animate custom properties on a linked rig ?

Here is a screen shot of the Rig's data panel after it has been linked and proxied. if you look at the bottom, the smirk property I wish to animate is locked. Is there a way to set it up so it stays accessible even when linked, like other properties of the piccolo_rig object are ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was going to the original armature and setting the custom property with the *Is Library Overridable*.

[image]

Comment: I'll have to give this a try ! Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes I ended up doing this. Worth noting that in the file where it is linked the property is not automatically overridable, you need to right click and set that in the Linked file as well. I guess Blender keeps these switches off by default to keep things running faster ?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use a workaround. Being able to use the custom properties would be a slick option as far as UI / user friendliness goes.
But for now I've decided to create one bone per face shape and treat them like sliders where translating the bone in Y axis would drive the face shape.
This works in linked files.
If anyone wants more details about this setup I can write up something.

Answer (score -1):

I think you will have to drive the custom property value with a bone, so it will be "proxied".

Comment: Hi. I think it would be useful if you could describe *how* the user should drive the property with the bone. What do they need to set up to do this?

Comment: Josh, Thanks for the reply. I added a screen shot of the panel, the custom property is part of an object that is proxied. Some of its properties are unlocked and others are locked. I wonder if there is a way to specify to a property to remain unlocked when linked ?